# rails divide loop in two tables. rails view, newbie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, view

wondering whats the best way to split up a loop on a model in the view onto TWO tables. seems simple enough.

```
   <div>
        <table>
          <tr><th>Refreshments and Exhibits</th></tr>
          <% @exhibitor.each do |exhibitor| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= exhibitor.name %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
          <tr><th>Refreshments and Exhibits</th></tr>
          <% @exhibitor.each do |exhibitor| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= exhibitor.name %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
     </div>
```

this displays the same table twice.  i want to loop through the @exhibitor to fill the td's in the first table, limit 15. then continue looping through the rest of the exhibitor.name for the second table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want tables of 15 do this

```
<% @exhibitors.each_slice(15) do |exhibitors_group| %>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr><th>Refreshments and Exhibits</th></tr>
      <% exhibitors_group.each do |exhibitor| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= exhibitor.name %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you want first 15 and the rest in other table do this

```
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr><th>Refreshments and Exhibits</th></tr>
      <% @exhibitor[0..15].each do |exhibitor| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= exhibitor.name %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>


  <div>
    <table>
      <tr><th>Refreshments and Exhibits</th></tr>
      <% @exhibitors[16..-1].each do |exhibitor| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= exhibitor.name %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
```

You should also consider 2 things:

- Use a helper or a layout for those tables
- Instead of slicing the array in the view do it in the controller

Comment: each_slice() doesn't quite do it.  If there's more than 30 items, then there will be a third table.  I think the answer needs to be first 15 and then all the rest

Comment: Actually you can put @exhibitors.each_slice((@exhibitors.count/2.0).ceil)) and you will always have two tables of the same length.